# Pandas compare two dataframes and remove what matches in one column

Tags: python, pandas

I have two separate pandas dataframes (`df1` and `df2`) which have multiple columns, but only one in common ('text').

I would like to do find every row in `df2` that does not have a match in any of the rows of the column that `df2` and `df1` have in common.

df1

```
A    B    text
45   2    score
33   5    miss
20   1    score
```

df2

```
C    D    text
.5   2    shot
.3   2    shot
.3   1    miss
```

Result df (remove row containing miss since it occurs in df1)

```
C    D    text
.5   2    shot
.3   2    shot
```

Is it possible to use the `isin` method in this scenario?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As you asked, you can do this efficiently using `isin` (without resorting to expensive `merge`s).

```
>>> df2[~df2.text.isin(df1.text.values)]
C   D   text
0   0.5 2   shot
1   0.3 2   shot
```

Answer (score 2):

You can merge them and keep only the lines that have a NaN.

```
df2[pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer').isnull().any(axis=1)]
```

or you can use `isin`:

```
df2[~df2.text.isin(df1.text)]
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

```
import numpy as np

mergeddf = pd.merge(df2,df1, how="left")

result = mergeddf[(np.isnan(mergeddf['A']))][['C','D','text']]
```