# Python - Compare 2 files with CSV module and 3 columns

Tags: python, csv, python-3.5

I'm trying to compare 2 files with Python CSV module.

1st CSV file like this:

```
Name N, Age, Pound
A, 1, 10
A, 2, 10
B, 2, 12
```

2nd CSV file:

```
Name N, Age, Pound
A, 1, 10
A, 3, 8
C, 1, 7
```

If column Name and column Age are equal return the Pound of both file in output.

Output file example:

```
Name, Age, Pound1, Pound2
A, 1, 10, 10
```

In Python 3.5 code:

```
import csv
import io

alist, blist = [], []

with open("hosts.csv", "r") as fileA:
    reader = csv.reader(fileA, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        alist.append(row)
with open("masterlist.csv", "r") as fileB:
    reader = csv.reader(fileB, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        blist.append(row)

first_set = set(map(tuple, alist))
secnd_set = set(map(tuple, blist))

matches = set(first_set).intersection(secnd_set)
print (matches)
```

But returns only the header...

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't mind using Pandas, there is a way of doing this by isin().

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34417964/pandas-compare-two-dataframes-and-remove-what-matches-in-one-column

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import csv
file1 = list(csv.reader(open('first.csv')))
file2 = list(csv.reader(open('second.csv')))
new_columns = [[a[0], a[1], a[-1], b[-1]] for a, b in zip(file1[1:], file2[1:]) if a[:2] == b[:2]]
write = csv.writer(open('outputfile.csv'))
write.writerow(new_columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it is to use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

# Load CSV files
df1 = pd.read_csv('first.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('second.csv')

# Merge tables
df = df1.merge(df2, on=['Name', 'Age'])

   Name   Age  Pound_x  Pound_y
0  A   1      10       10

# Rename Pound columns
df.rename(columns={'Pound_x': 'Pound1', 'Pound_y': 'Pound2'}, inplace=True)

   Name   Age  Pound1  Pound2
0  A   1      10       10

# Write output to file
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Yes! But here is not available pandas module, only csv... it's too bad...

Comment: You don't have permission (or can't get permission) to install pandas?