# How do i check if a value of DataFrame 'A' is there in DataFrame 'B' and write it to a new dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Need to compare the user id in column 'pk' of first dataframe with user id in column 'user__id'of second dataframe and copy the matching data to a new dataframe. Both dataframes are to be imported from two different csv files.

[Two dataframes to be compared for same user id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IvMC.png)

```html
DataFrame A (user.csv)

 pk  phone
0 4972619  797979797971
1 4972608  454959544952 
2 4972597  959594594543
3 4972596  454555545444 
4 4972595  554545545547 
5 4972594  555555555555 
6 4972593  979797979791 
7 4972592  959579999999 
8 4972591  557979557454

DataFrame B (item.csv) 

       user__id    user__phone
0 4972593  979797979791 
1 7674145  525575779792 
2 9251355  554755975999 
3 1015996  945595774994 
4 4704137  957425457575 
5 2120715  545575979755 
6 4972595  554545545547 
7 1726034  495597794559 
8 1102155  955755557579 
9 4972597  959594594543
```

Comment: Need the result as a new DataFrame 'C' with matching user id datas in column 'id_user' and phone number in 'phone_number'

Comment: would really appreciate if you can paste the data and expected output as text, no images please.

Comment: @anky_91 I made up this data and saved it as an image. Can't seem to find the text file. I'm sorry.

Comment: you can copy paste some samples as text atleast

Comment: @anky_91 tried the first solution in the actual data that i need to analyze https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34417964/pandas-compare-two-dataframes-and-remove-what-matches-in-one-column
but the end result i got in Jupyter notebook and Excel analysis are different.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101

Comment: @anky_91 question updated with sample data.

Comment: `df1.merge(df2,left_on=['pk'],right_on=['user__id'])` works?

Comment: @anky_91 Thanks a lot. It worked! :)
but i was not able to put it into a new dataframe. i did something like this:
df3=df1.merge(df2,left_on=['pk'],right_on=['user__id'])

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? -

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'pk' : np.random.randint(1,20,size=15)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'user_id' : np.random.randint(1,20,size=15)})
df3 = pd.merge(df,df2,left_on='pk',right_on='user_id',how='inner')
print(df3)


  ID
0   8
1   16
2   16
3   16
4   16
5   16
6   16
7   4
8   10
```